# Textarea padding inconsistency in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: html, css

I have a padding on my textarea element and I would like the content to remain padded as you scroll within the textarea. It is working as expected in Firefox but not in Chrome. The below image shows the difference in output:

[image]

CSS:

```
textarea { 
    width: 250px; 
    height: 160px; 
    padding: 15px; 
    font-family: Arial; 
    font-size: 12px; 
    line-height: 18px; 
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC; 
    overflow: auto; 
    resize: none;
}
```

In Chrome, the top and bottom padding only appears at the beginning and end of the text content. Here is a jsfiddle to demonstrate:

http://jsfiddle.net/LkE6f/

How can I make the padding in Chrome appear/render in the same way as it does in Firefox?

Comment: Working same for me on Chrome 36

Comment: Check this jsbin out and let us know if it gives you any insights: https://gist.github.com/gtramontina/3935597 http://jsbin.com/emowom/3

Comment: Interesting find. Personally, the Chrome way seems a lot more intuitively reasonable.

Comment: I have the same. But what is the question? This is how Chrome behaves and I think there's no workaround for this. It's not only for textarea but also for other elements when you have `overflow:` and `padding`.

Comment: Can we modify html to find a solution?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could do something like this, it's not very flexible (fixed width), but you can expand on it. It fixes the issue in Chrome and doesn't break Firefox. It uses pseudo-elements on `#container`, [which work in IE8+](http://caniuse.com/#search=:before)

```
textarea {
    width: 250px;
    height: 160px;
    padding: 15px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 18px;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    overflow: auto;
    resize: none;
    display: block;
}
#container:before, #container:after {
    display: block;
    height: 15px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    position: absolute;
    left: 1px;
    width: 225px;
    content:'';
}
#container:before {
    top: 1px;
}
#container:after {
    bottom: 6px;
}
```

Here's a <kbd>[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LkE6f/22/)</kbd>.

**Update:** Added `display: block` to `textarea` to fix IE positioning issue.

**Update 2:** Alternative solution which takes its width from the `#container` div and for which you'd need to set the `right` value based on the width of the scrollbar of the browser, the `17px` value is ok in Chrome at the moment. A pro with this solution is that you can set the width of the `textarea` to anything by changing the width of the `#container`, and the pseudo-elements will scale accordingly. <kbd>[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LkE6f/24/)</kbd>.

```
#container {
    width: 260px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    position: relative;
}
textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 160px;
    padding: 15px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 18px;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    overflow: auto;
    resize: none;
    display: block;
}
#container:before, #container:after {
    display: block;
    height: 15px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    position: absolute;
    left: 1px;
    right: 17px;
    content:'';
}
#container:before {
    top: 1px;
}
#container:after {
    bottom: 1px;
}
```

Comment: @misterManSam - I don't see the issue, I know browser scrollbar widths aren't uniform so I didn't try to get the width right, I've just left additional space as there is a `15px` margin on the left and right anyway..

Comment: @misterManSam - Ah I see, when there is no scrollbar, that can be fixed by adding some extra padding on the right.

Comment: Thanks @MathijsFlietstra, I'll give this a test soon and let you know if it works for me :)

Answer (score 3):

Best answer:

Embrace the difference between browsers; the web is not uniform and your design will never be 100% identical across browsers.

Work around answers:

If you don't care about the scrollbar having a gap at the top and bottom, you can [use borders and an outline like this](http://jsfiddle.net/LkE6f/23/).

**OR**

This can be achieved with a pseudo element, if you are happy wrapping each `textarea` in a `div`. Should display correctly on IE8+, FF and Chrome.

[Have a fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/LkE6f/21/)

HTML

```
<div class="textareaWrap">
    <textarea>Content</textarea>
</div>
```

CSS

```
textarea {
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
    height: 160px;
    font-family: Arial;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 18px;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    resize: none;
}
.textareaWrap {
    position: relative;
}
.textareaWrap:after {
    position: absolute;
    content:'';
    display: block;
    width: 232px;
    height: 15px;
    background: #FFF;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 1px;
}
.textareaWrap:before {
    position: absolute;
    content:'';
    display: block;
    width: 232px;
    height: 15px;
    background: #FFF;
    z-index: 1;
    top:1px;
    left: 1px;
}
```

Comment: Made a change of width. This would need to be fiddled with a little more possibly as IE, FF and Chrome are all rendering slightly differently by 1px here and there.

Answer (score -2):

Try the below solution for the textarea

```
textarea {
   -moz-appearance: textfield;
   -moz-binding: url("chrome://global/content/platformHTMLBindings.xml#inputFields");
   -moz-user-select: text;
   background-color: -moz-field;
   border: 2px inset threedface;
   color: -moz-fieldtext;
   cursor: text;
   font: -moz-field;
   width:250px;
   height:150px;
   letter-spacing: normal;
   line-height: normal !important;
   padding: 1px 0;
   text-align: start;
   text-indent: 0;
   text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
   text-shadow: none;
   text-transform: none;
   word-spacing: normal;
 }
```

Fiddle link [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/LkE6f/7/)

Regards
Mahadevan